# Android development, graphical layout?

Tags: android

Hi im just starting to make an app, and on eclipse i get 2 tabs. Graphical layout is one of them. I see a black cell phone screen and some buttons and text stuff to put on it. What is this for and how do i use it? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the graphical layout you can just drag and drop items in, and the xml is the actual code. Adding things via the graphical layout will edit your code for you, and visa versa. Personally I prefer to just use the xml because the graphical layout can be a little difficult to get the results you want, and it's always useful to have a good understanding of the xml code and how it works.

Answer (score 2):

Android uses [XML layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html). They can be a real pain to edit. The graphical layout tab with the picture of the phone is supposed to make it a little easier.

Sometimes you still have to dip down into the XML to get things just right, but the graphical layout will at least give you a preview.

Answer (score 1):

It's your Interface Builder. 
It builds interfaces ;)